# How to support Transactions in Neo4j Rest

Tags: grails, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, spring-transactions

We build a Grails Application using the database Neo4j ,And We used Spring Data Neo4j rest ,
As per the requirement of any Application , it should provide the facility of Transaction . But using Neo4j When we save a Node and Exception occur in executing the code then the node is save but its relationship is not save 
How to resolve this problem ???
Can we use Spring Transaction Management or any other thing ???

Answer (score 0):

In the past it was a shortcoming of the Neo4j-REST APIs to not expose transactions.

In the next milestone build 3.3.0.M01 we'll add support for remote transactions using the Cypher transactional endpoint. Please try with that version then and report back.

Comment: But we neads now , However when we use the grails plugin for the neo4j then it provide the Transaction , How is it possible ?

Comment: Two separate projects. If you want it now, use the Grails Plugin or the Neo4j-JDBC driver